# Creating private cocoapods repo outside github

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

We are working on projects which use both open-source libraries and our private libraries which can't go public. By public I mean, that they can't be hosted outside our company servers. We would like to use CocoaPods for all of them. While using open-source libs is pretty easy, my question is if I can use private repository on our private servers to host our private libs? I've found this link http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html, and there is no information weather it has to be github or it can be any server, however I was also looking for solution on other pages and everybody say that I has to be repo on github. Is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not have to be a repo on GitHub. See the [private pods](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) guide for more info.

Comment: So I can create Specs repository on my local git server and I can host all my code on the same server, right?

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot to include a link to guide on this topic, my bad. I have updated the answer with a link.  To answer your question; yes, you can host all of it on your own server.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to set it up first thing in the morning tommorow :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new local repo and configure the remote as needed:

```
mkdir ~/.cocoapods/repos/private
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/private
git init
git commit -m Initial
git remote add origin https://myremote.org
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I am trying to give my set of code to a client and I want to distribute that codes to clients so that he only can use it so I am using private repo with cocoapod. If I push the trunk pod to cocoapod will my private repos code will be published publicly?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can use any git repo you want.

I always follow this tutorial when create private cocoa pods.
https://coderwall.com/p/7ucsva

Answer (score 1):

it's simple 
write the following lines

```
mkdir ~/<path x>
cd <path x> 
git init
pod repo add <name of your repo> ~/<path x>
```